# What are maven coordinates of Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool?

Tags: java, tomcat, maven-2, maven

What are Maven coordinates of [Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the improved search functionality on the Maven Central Repository website you can query for artifacts by a given class name. The query [fc:"org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3a%22org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory%22) returns the following artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.42</version>
</dependency>
```

There are [multiple older versions and some newer RC versions](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.apache.tomcat%22%20AND%20a%3a%22tomcat-jdbc%22) available.

Comment: In both of them `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory` is available, right?

Comment: They both contain a org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.

Comment: If your are looking for that Class, have a look at the SpringSource repository: http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.org.apache.tomcat.jdbc&version=1.0.9.3

Comment: Tomcat documentation tells me to use that `DataSourceFactory` class, but neither JAR has it. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: This answer refers to DBCP, not the new tomcat JDBC pool referenced in the question's link.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I moved the answer from the comment to the answer itself. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 33):

The selected answer appears to be erroneous as it refers to spring rather than the artifact the quesitoner is looking for.  It can be found here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Version 7.0.19 and 7.0.20 are also available.